# Linking to CiviCRM forms from external sources - not working

Tags: contribution-page, registration

Whenever a CiviCRM URL is used in external content such as a Mailchimp email, a bit.ly link, even social media, the page loads fine but submitting it either kicks the user back to the homepage, or results in a "too many redirects" error. We have sh404SEF enabled but no matter what setting it is on, this problem persists.

Comment: care to paste example paths in question - and what your cms is

Comment: What happens if the same url is entered into browser directly and the form submitted? Can you see if there is anything different in the url's between the two processes, such as an extra &key=value of some sort? Is it possible there is a difference between logged in users hitting the url and then a non-logged in user doing the same? Or between the roles of different users testing one method versus the other?